# Istio AuthorizationPolicy Not Allowing Requests from Init Containers in Kubernetes Job

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm encountering an issue with Istio AuthorizationPolicy in my Kubernetes cluster:

I have a Kubernetes Job in the default namespace and migration service account running migrations for my db which is in a separate pod in the same namespace.
This migration job contains both main containers and init containers.
I've applied an Istio AuthorizationPolicy to allow traffic to the db from the migration service account.
The problem is that the AuthorizationPolicy doesn't seem to be allowing requests from the init containers, even though they should match the allowed criteria of the specified service account.

Here are some details of my setup:

Kubernetes version: 1.27.2
Istio version: 1.17.2
Kubernetes Namespace: default
Service Account: migration

AuthorizationPolicy:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-db-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            principals: ["cluster.local/ns/default/sa/migration"]
```

Migration job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: migration-{{ randAlphaNum 8 | lower }}
spec:
  completions: 1
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: migration
      restartPolicy: Never
      initContainers:
        - name: "check-db-ready"
          image: "postgres:9.6.24"
          command: ["sh", "-c"]
          args:
            - |
              until pg_isready -d "postgresql://$(DB_WRITE_USER):$(DB_WRITE_PASS)@{{ $.Values.db.host }}";
              do
                echo "Waiting for database service";
                sleep 2;
              done;
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: {{ envSecretName }}
        - name: "check-database-exists"
          image: "postgres:9.6.24"
          command: [ "sh", "-c" ]
          args:
            - |
              echo "Creating database $(DB_NAME)"
              createdb --maintenance-db="postgresql://$(DB_WRITE_USER):$(DB_WRITE_PASS)@{{ $.Values.db.host }}/template1" $(DB_NAME)
              exit_code=$?
              if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Database $(DB_NAME) created successfully."
              else
                echo "error creating database $(DB_NAME)"
              fi
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: {{ envSecretName }}
        - name: {{ migration.name }}
          image: {{ migration.image }}
          args:
            {{  range migration.args }}
              - {{ . }}
            {{ end }}
          env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: {{ db.host }}
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: {{ envSecretName }}
      containers:
        - name: "seed-db"
          image: "postgres:9.6.24"
          command: [ "sh", "-c" ]
          args:
            {DB SEEDING}
          env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: {{ db.host }}
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: {{ envSecretName }}
```

The policy should be allowing the migration to run successfully, instead the check-db-ready init container is hanging on running and logging `db:5432 - no response Waiting for database service`

What I've Checked So Far:

The configuration appears to be correct, with the namespace and service account correctly specified in the migration pod.
I've confirmed that the pods (both init and main containers) are run successfully when no authorization policy is applied.
The db authorization policy also works as expected when applied to allow other pods in the namespace.

Is there a reason the authorization policy is blocking the init containers?

Comment: Can you check if db is [running](https://opennms.discourse.group/t/how-to-figure-out-if-postgresql-database-is-running/227) and make sure that port 5432 is open in firewall and listening in db.